# NSIS, do not go to next page

Tags: nsis, wizard

I have an installer, where I ask the user whether s/he wants to continue onto the  next installation step or not.

How can I do so that if s/he clicks on "No", it won't go to the next installation step?

The Yes/No MessageBox must appear only when s/he clicks the Next button, so I defined some actions in MUI_PAGE_CUSTOMFUNCTION_LEAVE dir_leave.

I imagined that I could just jump back on dir_show, but I don't know how to do that.
Is there any better (more obvious) way?

Comment: I have found the answer. It is sufficient to use Abort, when user clicks no. The installer does not go to next page then...

Comment: Yes, that's it. You should write and answer and accept it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer. It is sufficient to use Abort, when user clicks no. The installer does not go to next page then...